# UITableView push to multi view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create table, and when click cell in table , the content will display in another view. Each of table has different design. How do I do that.

[image]

I don't enough to post image, you can see in this link. thanks.

Comment: Use the UITableViewDelegate method suggested by Ramdy, push another view controller in that method, pass all the required data to that controller and display it there, the way you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this delegate method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"InstructionToSection" sender:nil]; //"InstructionToSection" is seque name
}



-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    InstructionSectionViewController * instructSection = [segue destinationViewController];  // InstructionSectionViewController is ur next viewcontroller. 1st u need to import your destination viewcontroller in header
    instructSection.SelectedItem = @"Ur Passing value"; // selectedItem should be declare in InstructionSectionViewController as property, need to synthesize 

}
```

For more detail refer to this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/)

Comment: can i use segue ? 
ex:
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

Comment: ya , u should use segue, then only the value ll pass to next controller.

Comment: before tat , make me clear. do u want pass value to next controller or  just pushing to next controller??

Comment: i want pass value to next controller then pushing to other view, but i don't know how to do it. i'm newbie in Ios .
Can you describe it, thank you .

Comment: and in 1 application, how many navigation controller is best?